# Why do super sonic fighter jets have narrow waist?

Tags: supersonic

Some of the supersonic fighter jets (such as F-4 Phantom and F-5) have narrow waist on their fuselage.

[image: for F-4]

[image: and for F-5]

Why do these fighter jets have narrow waist?

Comment: See [this question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/7451/19) about the area rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is likely due to application of the [Area rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_rule), which helps to reduce drag due to shock waves in transonic and supersonic flight.

It basically is an attempt to keep the cross-sectional area of the craft from varying rapidly as you move along the length.  So at a point where the wings area is increasing a lot, the area of the fuselage may be reduced to compensate.

This reduction of area is mainly intended when these airplanes fly at transonic speeds (0.8-1.2) but not when flying at supersonice speeds where a front shock wave is created.

Comment: I was not aware of the area rule for transoceanic fly.  Thanks for detailed answer.